# display wrapper class list of account records?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Hi I am trying to display list of account records and display total count in output text using remote action method for that I created one wrapper class and did some code but I am not getting records from wrapper account. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc7FM.png) what I am getting when using `alert(result)`

Controller:

```
public class exremote {
    public static list<account> listacc{get;set;}
    public static integer count{get; set;}

    @remoteaction
    public static wrappercls getaccounts(){
        string account = 'select id,name,accountnumber from account';
        listacc = database.query(account);
        count = listacc.size();
        system.debug('#####'+count);
        wrappercls wra = new wrappercls(count,listacc);
        return wra;
    }

    public class wrappercls{
        public integer count11;
        public list<account> account;

        public wrappercls(integer count11,list<account> account){
            this.count11 = count11;
            this.account = account;
        }
    }
}
```

page:

```
<script>
  function getallaccounts(){
    exremote.getaccounts(
        function(result,event){
            if(event.status){

            }
            else {

            }
       },{escape:true}
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why use remoting? Why use `alert`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Thanks for Responding used remote action for maintain view state.And used alert for reference only no need to use just see before what i am getting  in result.